# Place Plane Geometry in Circle using Three.js

Tags: three.js, geometry

I have been able to place a group of BoxGeometry objects in a circle.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    angle = (i / (20/2)) * Math.PI;
    cube .position.x = (50 * Math.cos(angle));
    cube .position.z = (50 * Math.sin(angle));
    cube .position.y = 5;
    scene.add(cube);
}
```

But the following only places a group of PlaneGeometry objects in a half circle.

```
var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('../images/texture.png')
    });
img.map.needsUpdate = true;


for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10),img);
    plane.overdraw = true;

    angle = (i / (20/2)) * Math.PI;
    plane.position.x = (50 * Math.cos(angle));
    plane.position.z = (50 * Math.sin(angle));
    plane.position.y = 5;
    scene.add(plane);
}
```

How can the PlaneGeometry objects be positioned in a full circle? Why is it only half a circle when using PlaneGeometry, and the same equations?

Comment: The circumference of a circle is `2.0*Math.PI` and not `Math.PI`

Comment: @Rabbid76 But he uses `(20/2)` in angle expression (yes, strange formulation).

Comment: Try making the material double-sided (`img.side = THREE.DoubleSide;`). In certain camera positions, half of the planes could be omitted due to back-face culling.